# jbpm 6.1 remote client not get initialized

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jbpm

I am trying to write a remote jbpm client service in springboot here is the code:

```
package socius.test.controller;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.kie.api.runtime.process.ProcessInstance;
import org.kie.api.task.TaskService;
import org.kie.services.client.api.RemoteRestRuntimeFactory;
import org.kie.services.client.api.command.RemoteRuntimeEngine;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;()
@RestController
public class JbpmRestController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/testClient")
    public List loginHome() throws MalformedURLException{


        ArrayList<Object> res=new ArrayList<Object>();
        String deploymentId="contego:RightToWork-prototype:1.0";
        String username="uname";
        String password="password";
        URL baseUrl = new URL("http://abc/business-central/");


        RemoteRestRuntimeFactory restSessionFactory  = new RemoteRestRuntimeFactory(deploymentId,baseUrl,username,password);

        // Create KieSession and TaskService instances and use them

          RemoteRuntimeEngine engine = restSessionFactory.newRuntimeEngine();

          KieSession ksession = engine.getKieSession();

          TaskService taskService = engine.getTaskService();


          ProcessInstance processInstance = ksession.startProcess("id");

          res.add(processInstance.toString());
          return res;

    }
```

ksession and taskService are successfully created. When I call "startProcess" method on ksession, it will run in to following error :

```
org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type text/html;charset="utf-8" and type null
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.createResponseFailure(BaseClientResponse.java:523)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.createResponseFailure(BaseClientResponse.java:514)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.readFrom(BaseClientResponse.java:415)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:377)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:350)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:344)
    at org.kie.services.client.api.command.AbstractRemoteCommandObject.executeRestCommand(AbstractRemoteCommandObject.java:406)
    at org.kie.services.client.api.command.AbstractRemoteCommandObject.execute(AbstractRemoteCommandObject.java:120)
    at org.drools.core.command.impl.CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.startProcess(CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.java:230)
    at org.drools.core.command.impl.CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.startProcess(CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.java:221)
    at socius.test.controller.JbpmRestController.loginHome(JbpmRestController.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
```

my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>basics.in.java.blogspot</groupId>
    <artifactId>basicsInJavaBlogspot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>basicsInJavaBlogspot</name>
    <description>A simple crud application using spring mvc jpa and hibernate</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>      
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie.remote</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-services-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jettison-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.6.Final</version>
</dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

        <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

I think the 'org.jboss.resteasy' dependency have some version mismatch or so. and i am facing another problem as well, it says here RemoteRestRuntimeFactory is deprecated , jbpm 6.1 documentation says we can use RemoteRestRuntimeFactory object to create remote rest session. is there any other way to create remote client object to communicate workbench ?

Comment: This isn't specific to jboss/jbpm, but seems to be a maven/dependency issue.  You may want to add "resteasy" and "maven" as tags on your question to get broader review.  May also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453183/resteasy-unable-to-find-messagebodyreader