# RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type class org.keycloak.representations.AccessTokenResponse

Tags: java, jackson, resteasy, keycloak

I'm trying to test Keycloak REST API.
Instaled the version 2.1.0.Final.
I can access the admin through browser with SSL without problems.

I'm using the code above:

```
Keycloak keycloakClient = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
.serverUrl("https://keycloak.intra.rps.com.br/auth")
.realm("testrealm")
.username("development")
.password("development")
.clientId("admin-cli")
.resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build())
.build();
List<RealmRepresentation> rr = keycloakClient.realms().findAll();
```

And got the error:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type class org.keycloak.representations.AccessTokenResponse

javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type class org.keycloak.representations.AccessTokenResponse
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.extractResult(ClientInvocation.java:141)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.extractors.BodyEntityExtractor.extractEntity(BodyEntityExtractor.java:60)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:104)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.grantToken(Unknown Source)
at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.grantToken(TokenManager.java:85)
at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessToken(TokenManager.java:65)
at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessTokenString(TokenManager.java:60)
at org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.BearerAuthFilter.filter(BearerAuthFilter.java:52)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:413)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:102)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.findAll(Unknown Source)
at br.com.rps.itsm.sd.SgpKeycloakClient.doGet(SgpKeycloakClient.java:71)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type class org.keycloak.representations.AccessTokenResponse
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientReaderInterceptorContext.throwReaderNotFound(ClientReaderInterceptorContext.java:42)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.getReader(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:75)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:52)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:59)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:55)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readFrom(ClientResponse.java:251)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:181)
at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.readEntity(BuiltResponse.java:213)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.extractResult(ClientInvocation.java:105)
```

I added the dependencies above, but do not solve my problem:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any clues?

Comment: Did you solved ? I got same message...

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RestEasy - Unable to find MessageBodyReader?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453183/resteasy-unable-to-find-messagebodyreader)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved !! 
You must add org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJacksonProvider into META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers file then run your executable jar.

Comment: or
  org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider

Comment: Do you have a solution when using maven ?

Comment: Same problem. I had already added resteasy-jackson2-provider in the pom and still had this problem.

Comment: No no no... jackson for read(but in earlier version of resteasy), jackson2 for write(now, only, I don't understand but seems it's separated now). Even though checking the hierarchy of classes, Jackson2Provider seems inherits MessageBodyReader. So strange.

Answer (score 32):

I used the dependency to fix this issue

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

Or if you create client with proxy then better to initialize provider factory before:

```
    ResteasyProviderFactory instance=ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();
    RegisterBuiltin.register(instance);
    instance.registerProvider(ResteasyJackson2Provider.class);
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding what [Dmitry pointed out here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48658107/2900795) for me causes the following warning:

```
WARN: RESTEASY002155: Provider class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider is already registered.  2nd registration is being ignored.
```

Probably [as Bacon said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46094946/2900795) the provider is automatically registered by simply adding the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the problem, that [MatteoM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46094946/1163329) pointed out. I solved with maven-shade-plugin and the transformes tag. Maybe it helps someone.

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>de.example.MainClass</Main-Class>
                                    <X-Compile-Source-JDK>1.8</X-Compile-Source-JDK>
                                    <X-Compile-Target-JDK>1.8</X-Compile-Target-JDK>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <artifactSet/>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-fat.jar</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Adding transformer for `META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers` works.

Comment: There's now a [ServicesResourceTransformer](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ServicesResourceTransformer) that takes care of all service provider files so that you don't have to specify each manually (and potentially forget some).

Answer (score 2):

Have you registered an instance of `@Provider` when creating the target/client? I see you haven't.

In my case, I was moving from Resteasy 3 to Resteasy 4, and receiving content type `text/plain`. In Resteasy-jaxrs 3, I used `ResteasyJackson2Provider` and it implements `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter`, and it worked. Now, in Restyeasy 4, the content type check seems to be stricter and `isReadable()` of this same named class only accepts `Content-Type` of `null` or contains `json`. As I receive `text/plain`, it no longer works.

For reading plain text, I suggest using `StringTextStar`. A new class in Resteasy 4.7.5, and it seems to work. Reading inputstream and write as string, just what I need. Check its impl.

```
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClient().uri(...)
                          .register(new ResteasyJackson2Provider()) // now only for writing
                          .register(new StringTextStar());         // use this for reading
```

And I think you are fine.

Answer (score 1):

On a wildfly 11 / Keycloak context, the following made it work with the `RestEasyClientBuilder`.

```
ResteasyClientBuilder builder = new ResteasyClientBuilder();
ResteasyProviderFactory providerFactory = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();
builder.providerFactory(providerFactory);
```

Double check if `ResteasyProviderFactory` defaults to `true` with your Resteasy version. If not, set the builtIns manually:

```
ResteasyProviderFactory.setRegisterBuiltinByDefault(true);
// or if ResteasyProviderFactory was already instantiated
RegisterBuiltin.register(providerFactory);
```

Comment: You saved my week with the first part of your answer. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I traced the root issue to the fact that I switched to `CompletableFuture`.

The version of the client used is probably outdated or something and while it works from eclipse, from an external executable it crashes with this error.

I'll probably post a fix, but it's going to either be: update the library or stop using the CompletableFuture on this library.

Comment: or switch from Resteasy to something else if possible