# Keycloak admin-client: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json

Tags: spring, jackson, jax-rs, resteasy, keycloak

I'm new to keycloak and spring. I'm trying to use the keycloak admin-client to create a user in my spring-boot project like this:

```
    Keycloak kc = Keycloak.getInstance(
    "http://localhost:8080/auth",
    "master", // the realm to log in to
    "admin", "password",  // the user
    "admin-cli");

    CredentialRepresentation credential = new CredentialRepresentation();
    credential.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
    credential.setValue("test123");

    UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
    user.setUsername("testuser");
    user.setFirstName("Test");
    user.setLastName("User");
    user.setCredentials(Arrays.asList(credential));

    kc.realm("master").users().create(user);
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type class org.keycloak.representations.AccessTokenResponse
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.extractResult(ClientInvocation.java:158)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.extractors.BodyEntityExtractor.extractEntity(BodyEntityExtractor.java:60)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:107)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.grantToken(Unknown Source)
at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.grantToken(TokenManager.java:89)
at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessToken(TokenManager.java:69)
at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessTokenString(TokenManager.java:64)
at org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.BearerAuthFilter.filter(BearerAuthFilter.java:52)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:443)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:105)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.create(Unknown Source)
at me.phuongtm.KeycloakAdminClientDemoApplication.main(KeycloakAdminClientDemoApplication.java:68)
  Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type class org.keycloak.representations.AccessTokenResponse
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ClientReaderInterceptorContext.throwReaderNotFound(ClientReaderInterceptorContext.java:42)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.getReader(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:80)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:53)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readFrom(ClientResponse.java:266)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:196)
at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.readEntity(BuiltResponse.java:212)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.extractResult(ClientInvocation.java:122)
... 13 more
```

It seems to be a problem with RESTEASY, so I added resteasy-jackson2-provider as suggested by keycloak docs, but no luck.

Here are my pom.xml dependecies:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I spent hours and hours trying to find an answer, I even tried this MatteoM's solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40462534/7441720

But no luck.

I appreciate all the help I can get

**UPDATE:**

It appears to be an issue of providers:

```
  10:06:45.027 [main] WARN org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n - 
RESTEASY002145: NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load builtin provider 

org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider from 
 jar:file:/C:/Users/hp/.m2/repository/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jackson2-
  provider/3.1.4.Final/resteasy-jackson2-provider-3.1.4.Final.jar!/META-
  INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers
```

I can't seem to find a solution, I checked the jar and the class

```
  ResteasyJackson2Provider
```

exists!

**UPDATE:**

From what I can tell, it was an issue with dependecies, I switched to gradle (but it should work for maven as well), my new dependencies are:

```
compile('org.keycloak:keycloak-admin-client:3.2.1.Final')
compile('org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:3.0.14.Final')
compile('org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-multipart-provider:3.0.14.Final')
compile('org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider:3.0.14.Final')
compile('org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxb-provider:3.0.14.Final')
compile('org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jettison-provider:3.0.14.Final')
compile('org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs:jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec:1.0.0.Final')
```

As for keycloak, I created a Configuration class with a bean:

```
@Bean
    public Keycloak keycloakBeanConfig(){
        return KeycloakBuilder.builder().serverUrl(keycloakUrl).realm(realm) //
                .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS).clientId(clientId) //
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: Use right version of resteasy-client  i.e  "3.0.14.Final" ,  as per the dependency  page https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-admin-client/3.2.0.Final

Comment: Did you find a solution to that ? I am facing the exact same problem !

Answer (score -1):

try to use `resteasy-jackson-provider` and remove`resteasy-jackson2-provider`. you can find dependency below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The problem with resteasy-jackson-provider is that it doesn't recognize the following: Unrecognized field "access_token" (Class org.keycloak.representations.AccessTokenResponse), not marked as ignorable. 
According to keycloak docs, we should use resteasy-jackson2-provider